# Linker errors when building a simple c++ program with ffmpeg

Tags: c++, cmake, ffmpeg

I have this c++ program:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C"
{
    #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
    #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
    #include <libswscale/swscale.h>

}

namespace hrean::ffmpeg
{
namespace detail
{
    
}//namespace detail

void testFFmpeg()
{
    AVFormatContext *avFormatContext = avformat_alloc_context();
    //I can comment out the rest of the function, the error is the same

} //testFFmpeg()

} //namespace hrean::ffmpeg


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    try
    {
        hrean::ffmpeg::testFFmpeg();
    }
    catch(const std::runtime_error& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error! " << e.what() << '\n';
        return -1;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cerr << "Unknown error\n";
        return -1;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The CMakeLists.txt for this is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(hrean)

add_subdirectory(lib/ffmpeg-module)

message("[temp] FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIRS = ${FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message("[temp] FFMPEG_LIBRARIES = ${FFMPEG_LIBRARIES}")
add_executable(hrean-app src/main.cpp)
target_include_directories(hrean-app PUBLIC ${FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(hrean-app PUBLIC ${FFMPEG_LIBRARIES})
```

The CMakeLists.txt for lib/ffmpeg-module contains only

```
find_package(FFmpeg REQUIRED MODULE)
```

The CMake output is:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.2") 
-- Checking for module 'libavcodec'
--   Found libavcodec, version 60.2.100
-- Checking for module 'libavformat'
--   Found libavformat, version 60.2.100
-- Checking for module 'libavdevice'
--   Found libavdevice, version 60.0.100
-- Checking for module 'libavutil'
--   Found libavutil, version 58.1.100
-- Checking for module 'libavfilter'
--   Found libavfilter, version 9.1.100
-- Checking for module 'libswscale'
--   Found libswscale, version 7.0.100
-- Checking for module 'libpostproc'
--   Found libpostproc, version 57.0.100
-- Checking for module 'libswresample'
--   Found libswresample, version 4.9.100
-- Found FFmpeg: /home/serban/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a;/home/serban/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavformat.a;/home/serban/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavutil.a  
[temp] FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIRS = /home/serban/ffmpeg_build/include
[temp] FFMPEG_LIBRARIES = /home/serban/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a;/home/serban/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavformat.a;/home/serban/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavutil.a
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/serban/Work/hrean/build
```

When I run make, I get the following errors. The problem is, this worked perfectly yesterday and I changed nothing. I create a new Ubuntu virtual machine, everything fresh and I still get the same problem. The output is 1000+ lines long, here is some of it:

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/hrean-app.dir/src/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable hrean-app
/usr/bin/ld: /home/serban/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavformat.a(amvenc.o): in function `amv_write_packet':
/home/serban/ffmpeg/libavformat/amvenc.c:356: undefined reference to `av_packet_unref'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/serban/ffmpeg/libavformat/amvenc.c:357: undefined reference to `av_packet_ref'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/serban/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavformat.a(amvenc.o): in function `amv_deinit':
/home/serban/ffmpeg/libavformat/amvenc.c:209: undefined reference to `av_packet_free'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/serban/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavformat.a(amvenc.o): in function `amv_init':
/home/serban/ffmpeg/libavformat/amvenc.c:111: undefined reference to `avcodec_get_name'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/serban/ffmpeg/libavformat/amvenc.c:117: undefined reference to `avcodec_get_name'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/serban/ffmpeg/libavformat/amvenc.c:188: undefined reference to `av_new_packet'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/serban/ffmpeg/libavformat/amvenc.c:196: undefined reference to `av_packet_alloc'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/serban/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavformat.a(asfdec_o.o): in function `asf_read_close':
/home/serban/ffmpeg/libavformat/asfdec_o.c:1413: undefined reference to `av_packet_free'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/serban/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavformat.a(asfdec_o.o): in function `asf_read_single_payload':
/home/serban/ffmpeg/libavformat/asfdec_o.c:1119: undefined reference to `av_new_packet'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/serban/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavformat.a(asfdec_o.o): in function `asf_read_packet':
/home/serban/ffmpeg/libavformat/asfdec_o.c:1388: undefined reference to `av_packet_move_ref'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/serban/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavformat.a(asfdec_o.o): in function `reset_packet':
/home/serban/ffmpeg/libavformat/asfdec_o.c:1030: undefined reference to `av_packet_unref'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/serban/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavformat.a(asfdec_o.o): in function `asf_deinterleave':
/home/serban/ffmpeg/libavformat/asfdec_o.c:1313: undefined reference to `av_packet_unref'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/serban/ffmpeg/libavformat/asfdec_o.c:1314: undefined reference to `av_packet_from_data'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/serban/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavformat.a(asfdec_o.o): in function `asf_read_replicated_data':
/home/serban/ffmpeg/libavformat/asfdec_o.c:1043: undefined reference to `av_new_packet'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/serban/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavformat.a(asfdec_o.o): in function `asf_read_timestamp':
/home/serban/ffmpeg/libavformat/asfdec_o.c:1463: undefined reference to `av_packet_alloc'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/serban/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavformat.a(asfdec_o.o): in function `reset_packet':
/home/serban/ffmpeg/libavformat/asfdec_o.c:1030: undefined reference to `av_packet_unref'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/serban/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavformat.a(asfdec_o.o): in function `asf_read_timestamp':
/home/serban/ffmpeg/libavformat/asfdec_o.c:1512: undefined reference to `av_packet_unref'
```

Any idea how to debug this?

Later edit:
This is the find script I am using: [FindFFmpeg.cmake](https://github.com/snikulov/cmake-modules/blob/master/FindFFmpeg.cmake)
I changed the way I link to the libraries, this way causes the least amount of errors:

```
set(ORDERED_FFMPEG_LIBRARIES ${AVFORMAT_LIBRARIES} ${AVCODEC_LIBRARIES} ${AVUTIL_LIBRARIES})
message("[temp] ORDERED_FFMPEG_LIBRARIES=${ORDERED_FFMPEG_LIBRARIES}")
add_executable(hrean-app src/main.cpp)

target_include_directories(hrean-app PUBLIC ${FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(hrean-app PUBLIC ${ORDERED_FFMPEG_LIBRARIES})
```

The errors are similar, but they seem to point to other locations:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable hrean-app
/usr/bin/ld: /home/serban/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavformat.a(mov.o): in function `mov_read_cmov':
/home/serban/ffmpeg/libavformat/mov.c:5578: undefined reference to `uncompress'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/serban/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavformat.a(swfdec.o): in function `swf_read_packet':
/home/serban/ffmpeg/libavformat/swfdec.c:393: undefined reference to `uncompress'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/serban/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavformat.a(swfdec.o): in function `swf_read_header':
/home/serban/ffmpeg/libavformat/swfdec.c:161: undefined reference to `inflateInit_'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/serban/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavformat.a(swfdec.o): in function `zlib_refill':
/home/serban/ffmpeg/libavformat/swfdec.c:134: undefined reference to `inflate'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/serban/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavformat.a(swfdec.o): in function `swf_read_close':
/home/serban/ffmpeg/libavformat/swfdec.c:557: undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
```

Do I have to link to anything else?

Regards,
Serban

Comment: "Any idea how to debug this?" - The missed functions (e.g. `av_packet_ref`) are from `libavcodec` library. While you link with that library, the positition of the linkage is wrong: because the library `libavformat` uses `libavcodec`, they should be linked in that order. Note, that variable `FFMPEG_LIBRARIES` doesn't preserve dependencies between ffmpeg libraries. Use variables `AVCODEC_LIBRARIES`, `AVFORMAT_LIBRARIES` and `AVUTIL_LIBRARIES` in the appropriate order. (Assuming you are using that [FindFFmpeg.cmake](https://github.com/snikulov/cmake-modules/blob/master/FindFFmpeg.cmake) script).

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for your answer! Yes, that's the FindFFmpeg.cmake script I copy-pasted. I did this:
set(ORDERED_FFMPEG_LIBRARIES ${AVFORMAT_LIBRARIES} ${AVCODEC_LIBRARIES} ${AVUTIL_LIBRARIES})  
target_link_libraries(hrean-app PUBLIC ${ORDERED_FFMPEG_LIBRARIES}) and now it's throwing less errors, like: /usr/bin/ld: /home/serban/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavformat.a(mov.o): in function `mov_read_cmov':
/home/serban/ffmpeg/libavformat/mov.c:5578: undefined reference to `uncompress' . They are similar, but it seems they point to different locations. Do I have to link to anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Not far ago ffmpeg became depended off **zlib**.
See [this](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/0e03807f698e3ee5584d89a8c77e7c9cf502b2e1/libavformat/mov.c#L70) include.

You may build ffmpeg without zlib

Or you may install zlib and link with it:

```
find_library(ZLIB NAMES z zlib REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(hrean-app PRIVATE ${ZLIB})
```